# How can I start calenderactivity via another application?

Tags: android

How can I start  calender activity via another application??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the other question you just [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430223/how-can-i-read-calender-notifications) I would advise you to be more precise in what you actually ask. This would help you get the answer you would like. For the question you have posed I can not say whether it is programming related or just a matter of using your Android phone.